Computing the principal argument of $z^n$
The number $$z_0=\bigg(\frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)^3$$
equals $1$. Its principal argument is therefore zero, and I follow the convention $Arg z \in(-\pi,\pi]$. But considering Euler's formula for $z=-1+i\sqrt{3}$, and then $$(re^\theta)^3=r^3e^{3\theta}  \tag{$\star$}$$
where $\theta$ denotes the principal argument, I might expect that $\theta(z^3)=3\theta(z)$. Yet $\theta(z)=(2/3)\pi$, and multiplying by three does not give us $\theta(z^3)=\theta(z_0)=0$. Is $(\star)$ always false, then?

I assume you meant $z^3 = (re^{i\theta(z)})^3 = r^3e^{i3\theta(z)}$. This equality is always true even if $3\theta(z)$ is not always the principal argument of $z^3$. It will however always be true that $\theta(z^3) \equiv 3\theta(z)$ mod $2\pi$.
